# Woocommerce Cart not clearing

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, cart, checkout, w3-total-cache

I know there will be this type of questions but i have tried almost all options without luck so i'm asking here.

I have issue that `cart` is not empty in woocommerce after order completed and also some users just add items to cart then not go to checkout and after somedays come back again they still see old cart.

I think it may be caching issue as i'm using `W3-total-cache` plugin.

I want to clear cart data after checkout or if user add items to cart and not checkout and after a while come back again for shopping then cart must be empty and should not store old session to cart.

I tried below code but no luck :

```
function nom_empty_cart_init_login(){
    $opt = get_option('nom_empty_cart_browser_close_do_login');
    $opt = $opt != 1 ? false : true;

    if( $opt ){
        session_destroy();
    }
}

//  destroy session on user logout
function nom_empty_cart_init_logout(){
    $opt = get_option('nom_empty_cart_browser_close_do_logout');
    $opt = $opt != 1 ? false : true;

    if( $opt ){
        session_destroy();
    }
}

add_action('admin_menu','nom_empty_cart_init_admin_init');
function nom_empty_cart_init_admin_init(){
    add_options_page( 'Woocommerce Clear Cart on Browser Closing', 'WC Clear Cart on Browser Close', 'manage_options', 'wc-clear-cart-on-browser-close', 'wc_clear_cart_on_browser_close' );    
}

function wc_clear_cart_on_browser_close(){

    if( isset( $_REQUEST['save_accconc'] ) and wp_verify_nonce($_REQUEST['wc-clear-cart-on-browser-close-name'],'wc-clear-cart-on-browser-close-action')):

        //  SAVING THE FORM DATA

            //  enable wcccobc
            if( isset($_REQUEST['enable_wcccobc']) )
                update_option('nom_empty_cart_browser_close_enable',1);

            //  enable wcccobc on login
            if( isset($_REQUEST['enable_wcccobc_on_login']) )
                update_option('nom_empty_cart_browser_close_do_login',1);

            //  enable wcccobc on logout
            if( isset($_REQUEST['enable_wcccobc_on_logout']) )
                update_option('nom_empty_cart_browser_close_do_logout',1);


        //  SAVING ;) ENDS

    endif;

    ?>
    <div class="wrap">
        <div class="inside">
            <h2>Woocommerce Clear Cart on Browser Closing</h2>
            <p>Note: the cart will be empty if the visitor close the whole browser, not just the widow. (will be updated soon)</p>

            <form action="<?php admin_url('options-general.php?page=wc-clear-cart-on-browser-close');?>" method="post">
                <?php wp_nonce_field('wc-clear-cart-on-browser-close-action','wc-clear-cart-on-browser-close-name')?>
                <p>
                    <input id="enable_wcccobc" type="checkbox" class="checkbox" name="enable_wcccobc" value="1" <?php checked(get_option('nom_empty_cart_browser_close_enable'),'1');?>>
                    <label for="enable_wcccobc" >Enable clear cart on browser closing</label>                   
                </p>
                <p>
                    <input id="enable_wcccobc_on_login" type="checkbox" class="checkbox" name="enable_wcccobc_on_login" value="1" <?php checked(get_option('nom_empty_cart_browser_close_do_login'),1);?>>
                    <label for="enable_wcccobc_on_login" >Enable clear cart on on user login</label>                    
                </p>
                <p>
                    <input id="enable_wcccobc_on_logout" type="checkbox" class="checkbox" name="enable_wcccobc_on_logout" value="1" <?php checked(get_option('nom_empty_cart_browser_close_do_logout'),1);?>>
                    <label for="enable_wcccobc_on_logout">Enable clear cart on user logout</label>                  
                </p>
                <p>
                    <input type="submit" class="button-primary" value="Save" name="save_accconc">
                </p>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php 
}
```

Comment: Regarding the cart not clearing after checkout, have you tried disabling all plugins except woocommerce and using a default theme to ensure it's not a plugin/theme conflict?

Comment: yes have tried that and also disabled w3 total cache too.

Answer (score 6):

I'm using method from @shoelaced and it work.
edit on theme's functions.php

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_payment_complete', 'order_received_empty_cart_action', 10, 1 );
function order_received_empty_cart_action( $order_id ){
    WC()->cart->empty_cart();
}
```

Comment: A custom plugin is a much better place for this sort of thing, just create a new folder in plugins called custom with a custom.php file that has this header: `/*Plugin Name: Custom Stuff
Description: Custom Functions, etc.
*/`

Comment: @jjxtra - Can you explain (or point me to some info) why it would be better to put this one action into a plug-in rather than into functions.php?

Comment: Your functions.php could get blown away when you update wordpress

Comment: only if you're using a wordpress theme. if you're using a custom theme, a wordpress update will not cause your functions.php to be blown away

Comment: Just in relation to this thread of comments - If you place a copy of your functions.php in your child theme it won't be overwritten by theme updates, functions.php also isn't affected by Wordpress updates as claimed above. Plugins also cause code bloat and poor performance, therefore the functions.php file is 100% the right place for this code.

Comment: It's recommended this type of function go into a plugin. Functions.php should be theme-specific functions, not platform-specific functions (e.g. you would not want to lose this functionality if you changed themes). Plugins don't slow sites down or add bloat anymore than the functions.php does, it is the code in the plugin or functions file that will cause the issue.